# Combining cell contents in one column using logic from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to combine and list the cell contents from one column using logic derived from another  See details below

**Data Set**

```
Name             Sales order number

Harry1           1234
Dave2            1235
Mary3            1234
Bill4            1234
Tom5             1235
```

The formula will look at sales order numbers, collect all of the names with the same sales order number and display the names in a single column called "Sold by"

**Results**

```
  Name            Sales Order Number            Sold by

Harry1            1234                          Harry1, Mary3, Bill4
Dave2             1235                          Dave2, Tom5
Mary3             1234                          Harry1, Mary3, Bill4
Bill4             1234                          Harry1, Mary3, Bill4
Tom5              1235                          Dave2, Tom5
```

It may seem illogical to do it this way but I've got a huge data set and would then do a Pivot using the "Results"

By doing a simple IF statement I've pulled the first name into the sold by column but can't seem to figure out how to aggregate all of the names with the same sales order and list them in the column

Comment: With a huge data set this will not be possible with a simple formula. Seems like some sorting and a pivot table would be your best bet without VBA

Comment: OK by huge I mean 26k rows.. we have other data sets that max out the first tab of the excel sheet and force us to use a new tab but I won't be applying this logic to that sheet.

Comment: Have you thought of moving to a relational database?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this transformation step with the free Microsoft [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) add-in.
It's not VBA, but in this case, there is some steps to code, beside the use of the UI.

[image: dataset -> data output from Power Query]
Table "Dataset"  -> data output from Power Query

1. Define the Dataset as table  (I call it "Dataset" in the following script)
2. On the ribbon Power Query, import the table in the UI ("From Table")
3. Put the script below in the advanced editor (ribbon View -> advanced editor)

Here is the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Dataset"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Sales order number", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Sales order number"},#"Changed Type",{"Sales order number"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),

    // Function for Merging the matching rows
    List_MatchingRows=(Table, Column) =>
        let 
            ColumnToMerge = Table.SelectColumns(Table, Column),
            ListMatch = Table.ToList(ColumnToMerge),
            SingleLine = Text.TrimEnd(Text.TrimEnd(Lines.ToText(ListMatch, ", ")," "),",")
        in
            SingleLine,


    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Sold by", each List_MatchingRows([NewColumn],"Name")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"NewColumn"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```